# foreach not returning a single value

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I've written the below code to return a single value from the table but it doesn't seem to be working. Any idea why?

```
$pmname = $pdo->quote($_SESSION['pmname']);
$sql = "SELECT img FROM pm_user WHERE name=$pmname";
$result = $pdo->query($sql);
foreach ($result as $row) 
{
echo $row["img"];
}
```

Comment: @qeremy How do you deal with one rowset in PDO?

Comment: With that much info, there could be 1000 reasons... check *pmname*, DB content, DB connection, Session status to name a few

Comment: If you need a single value, so why do you using loop for it? Just get first value of result.

Comment: You should be preparing your queries - please see the edit to my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why aren't you `fetch`-ing anything? Try replaceing the `foreach` with:

```
while($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{
    echo $row['img'];
}
```

or even, if you're sure there is but one single row:

```
$row = $pdo->query('your query')->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
echo $row['img'];
```

Could well do the trick, though I haven't tried this - yet.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to do a `fetch` somewhere. If you would like to use a `foreach` structure, store the result set in a variable using `fetchAll` then loop over it.

```
$pmname = $pdo->quote($_SESSION['pmname']);
$sql = "SELECT img FROM pm_user WHERE name=$pmname";
$rows = $pdo->query($sql)->fetchAll();
foreach ($rows as $row) 
{
    echo $row["img"];
}
```

**Edit - and more importantly:**
You should **not** be just passing in `$pmname` in via the `quote` method. See the PHP manual PDO::quote

> If you are using this function to build SQL statements, you are
>   strongly recommended to use PDO::prepare() to prepare SQL statements
>   with bound parameters instead of using PDO::quote()

You should really be doing such as:

```
$sql = "SELECT img FROM pm_user WHERE name=:pmname";
$stm = $pdo->prepare( $sql );
$stm->execute( array( ':pmname' => $_SESSION['pmname'] ) );

$rows = $stm->fetchAll();
foreach ($rows as $row) 
{
    echo $row["img"];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should check always the input array variable for a foreach and number of rows returned from database. That avoid warnings/errors in production code when you don't get any value querying the dabatase.

In your example, you can check with empty() php function. For example:

```
$pmname = $pdo->quote($_SESSION['pmname']);
$result = $pdo->query("SELECT img FROM pm_user WHERE name=$pmname");

if($pdo->rowCount() > 0 && !empty($result))
{
    foreach ($result as $row) 
    {
        echo $row["img"];
    }
}
else
{
    echo 'No user image found in database.';
}
```